# Solving a first-order nonlinear differential equation: $y' + y = \frac{x}{y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y' + y = \frac{x}{y}$$

How do you solve this differential equation?

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [Bernoulli Differential Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) because it is in the form:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)y^n$$
These can be reduced into linear ODE's by substituting $v=y^{1-n}$.

---

Therefore in your case, you should substitute:
$$v=y^2 \iff \frac{dv}{dx}=2y\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$$
Multiplying your ODE on both sides by $2y$, we obtain:
$$2y\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}+2y^2=2x$$
Now the substitution is obvious:
$$\frac{dv}{dx}+2v=2x$$

This is a linear nonhomogeneous differential equation, which one may solve using integrating factors.

---

The integrating factor will be $\mu(x)=e^{\int 2~dx}=e^{2x}$. Therefore:
$$e^{2x}\frac{dv}{dx}+2e^{2x}\cdot v=2e^{2x}\cdot x$$
Substitute $2e^{2x}=\frac{d}{dx}(e^{2x})$, and apply the reverse product rule. The rest is easy.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$
y\cdot y'+y^2=x\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \frac12(y^2)'+y^2=x.
$$